# How to upload an image on eBay via Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, ebay-api

I'm trying to automate listings on eBay (I know I can use API but I prefer doing it with Selenium) but I'm stuck trying to upload an image to eBay.

The URL I am viewing is:

```
http://cgi5.ebay.com/ws/eBayISAPI.dll?LikeThisListing&cpg=20&aid=1&from=wn&sid=475543545921&itemid=290714408232&cat1=43537
```

You can replace `475543545921` with any item number. You'll need to login to your account to view this page I believe.

You can upload images by clicking on "Add/edit photos" or "Click to add photos"

Using the following syntax does not work:

```
  WebElement fileInput = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='ID']"));
  fileInput.sendKeys("C:\\PATH");
```

Does anyone know how I could upload images on eBay aside from using their API?